# serving the folder produce by pub build with the same server that serve the api (complete app)

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I would like to join my 2 apps written in dart:

- backend that serve the data (api)
- front with angulardart (build folder generated by pub build)

Pretty simple question I know but I don't usually do that, so I was wondering:

- Do I need to serve all the build folder ?
- A simple static file server can do that ?
- what package do you usually use ?
- any interesting links ?

Answer (score 1):

If your backend is written such that you have a script in your `bin` folder that uses `HttpRequest` then you need to host it in the Dart VM (by calling `dart bin\script.dart` . You cannot host it as static files like the frontend, because the dart files that should be executed would just be served up to the browser.

Depending on your operating system, you'd likely want to run this as some sort of service to avoid needing a user logged on to run it. The [Dart Docker images](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/docker-images-for-dart-now-available.html) might be a good way to do this.

If you want to serve the frontend code using the same server, then your backend will need to be able to serve up the static files when handling the request. You might be able to do this easily with the `shelf` package.

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example of full stack Dart application (backend + frontend) here: https://github.com/luizmineo/io_2014_contacts_demo

The server (backend) is configurable, so it can serve the client from any folder (usually, web or build/web). The example also includes a build script, which can be used to produce a deployable build (server + compiled client).